# How big is a stack?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I want to know how much a stack in Terraria is. I am able to get over at least 200 blocks, but I don't know how much more. I want to know because I am going around trying to get a ton of stone blocks for a big building. I want to know that if a stacks real high, I won't need that many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item type has a different stack size, with consumable items usually between 30 and 999.

Stone has a stack size of 999, as do many of the similar basic resources such as dirt and sand.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks like I might only need a stack or two :D

Comment: Bombs, Grenades, and Dynamite stack up to 99

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the item, weapons can only stack on one, the only weapons that can stack are Light Disks and Banarangs. Potions can only stack up to 30 when Explosives stack up to 99. Most blocks stack up to 999.